# r.js optimizer - don't mangle function names

Tags: javascript, requirejs, uglifyjs, r.js

I am using r.js with uglify to minify and concatenate my scripts. I am getting some errors on a production site where the stack trace returned is unintelligible. I would like to temporarily turn off the mangling of function names (variable names are fine) and am having trouble working out how to do this as r.js wraps the configuration options that are passed to uglify.js

The uglify config section in my r,js build config looks like this

```
uglify: {
      beautify: true,
      indent_start: 0,
      indent_level: 1,
   }
```

I would like to add the

> -nmf or --no-mangle-functions – in case you want to mangle variable names, but not touch function names. ([from here](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS))

If i add the line

```
uglify: {
      beautify: true,
      indent_start: 0,
      indent_level: 1,
      '--no-mangle-functions': true
   }
```

It does nothing, as does `'no-mangle-functions': true`.

How do I pass this option to uglify?

Comment: have you seen the example config file on their webpage: https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js ? There is this `no_mangle: true` option and a `mangle : false`option for r.js version 2

Comment: Yes, but this option only allows mangling or not, it does not allow you access to the full mangling options (I want to mangle the variable names, but not the function names)

Answer (score 3):

Trying to make uglified/mangled code readable kind of defeats it's purpose in the first place.
Probably, what you are after are [source maps](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/).

To generate source maps in Uglify just add these options:

```
uglify: {
    options: {
        sourceMap: 'build.min.map',
        sourceMappingURL: 'build.min.map'
    }
}
```

Map filename must mirror the final javascript filename:

```
uglified.js <=> uglified.map
```

Comment: Absolutely the right approach; however, I find that I'm having problems with the debuggers in Chrome and Firefox with source maps, so I'm tempted to use `mangle: false` as suggested by @pfried above (my problem is only reproducible in my staging and production environment, not in dev).

Answer (score 1):

From what i can see in the source code of r.js there is no direct differentiation between functions and variable names. But there is an option called `no_functions` which is actually passed to the uglify section where the default value is `false`

Passing of options:

https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/dist/r.js#L25067

Defaulting `no_functions`to `false`:

https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/dist/r.js#L11492

I cannot test it right now, so i am only guessing. Maybe you can try this option